# Sonarqube eclipse plugin issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, eclipse-luna, eclipse-mars

I've been trying to test SonarQube Plugin for Eclipse but neither Luna nor Mars seems to work, when going to preferences and try to open the Sonar settings I get this error:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui (1065).

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Hi! I enabled the automated bug message in Mars. Here is the detailed error. [link](https://dev.eclipse.org/recommenders/community/confess/#/incidents/3Zv7IAFeIGKC2kH15CStiIqM08NqEQ10VdXXh0W7bkHlqlNzJgsb8xqpi6WpcEQ1)

Comment: There is a conflict related to slf4j with another of your installed plugin (for example m2e, or spring tool suite). To avoid this issues I have removed all dependencies between SQ Eclipse and slf4j, it will be released in next version (3.5) that is close to development end.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Thanks. Ill wait for the release.